# Autogeneration Of Number in any of (C# / ASP.Net / Javascript/ MySQL)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, mysql, c#-4.0

We are creating **C# , ASP.Net** application.
I need to create autoGenerate ID's depending upon 5 groups & show it in textbox

Suppose there are **5 Groups**, (1000 -2000 is **Number Range for AutoGeneration** of No)

```
Group 1 ---> 1000-2000
Group 2 ---> 2001-3000
Group 3 ---> 3001-4000
Group 4 ---> 4001-5000
Group 5 ---> 5001-6000
```

For Group 1, first record no will be 1000, Next will be 1001 . but if user enter 1500 , it must take same no, 
But after that **Next time autogeneared no will be 1002 not 1501.**

How this logic should be implemented. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already tried anything? It sounds rather easy problem, so I'm curious where is the problem you've met.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql you could do

```
SELECT
  IF(MIN(myId) is null, @minimum, MIN(myId) + 1) AS nextId 
FROM
  myTable t1
    LEFT JOIN myTable t2
      ON t2.myId = (t1.myId + 1)
WHERE
  t2.myId is null
  AND t1.myId >= @minimum
LIMIT
  1
```

@minimum should be the start of the group range (eg 1000, 2000, etc)

In the other languages I suggest a simple for-loop

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve your desired result is to have a method that keeps track of only the auto-generated IDs. This method should only be invoked if the user doesn't enter their own ID. Should the user enter their own ID, do not invoke the auto-generate method.

This will work well until a point where the auto-generated ID, goes up to an ID that is 1 less that an ID that some user has picked. Should the auto-generate try to work there, it would generate an ID that is already in the system.

Therefore you will need logic in your auto generate method, to increment further in such a case. Until a valid ID is reached.